# adding words to qdap dictionary in R

Tags: r, dictionary, spell-checking, qdap

I am using qdap package for spell checking, but the default dictionary doesn't have many words such as cities,states, countries, or languages. I know I can add words to the dictionary like below

```
dict <- c(qdapDictionaries::GradyAugmented, "word1","word2","word3")
```

But I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to add about 1000 words to the dictionary.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you want to achieve? Where do you get your new words from? I'd say you could just put them into a character vector `v`, and then do `dict <- c(qdapDictionaries::GradyAugmented, v)`. Is there an efficiency problem with that?

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This answers my question.

Comment: You could have your words in a .csv file or so, read it into a vector and use it as Scarabee says.